# back bone local storage buf.copy is not a function

Tags: backbone.js, browserify

```
buffer.js:238
    buf.copy(buffer, pos);
        ^
```

TypeError: buf.copy is not a function
    at Function.Buffer.concat (buffer.js:238:9)

I am getting this error,when I try to include backbone.localstorage